# What was the fate of Luke’s landspeeder?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, luke-skywalker

Luke and Ben and the droids make it to Mos Eisley and mind trick their way past the troopers. That’s the last we see of the land speeder.

Was it just a loss that Luke wrote off when they had to flee Tatooine on the Falcon? Or did Luke take time to sell it for some extra cash between the cantina mess and the craziness in the hangar?

Any Canon or Legends information? (novelizations, comics, etc.)

Comment: Related, not dupe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49452/why-does-luke-say-hes-okay-with-having-to-sell-his-speeder

Comment: @Valorum I was trying to find that scene mentioned in that question and couldn't find it, thank you very much, I thought I was going crazy

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Canon(ish)

There was a scene in the [original screenplay](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) that addressed this. Luke sold it to a '*used speeder dealer*'. Beyond this, its fate is unknown.

> EXT. TATOOINE - MOS EISLEY - STREET - ALLEYWAY - [USED  SPEEDER LOT](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Spaceport_Speeders).
>
> Ben and Luke are standing in a sleazy used speeder lot,  talking with a tall, grotesque, insect-like used speeder dealer. Strange exotic bodies and spindly-legged beasts pass by as the insect concludes the sale by giving Luke some coins.
>
> **LUKE:** *He says it's the best he can do.  Since the XP-38 came out, they're just not in demand.*
>
> **BEN:** *It will be enough*.
>
> Ben and Luke leave the speeder lot and walk down the dusty
> alleyway past a small robot herding a bunch of anteater-like
> creatures. Luke turns and gives one last forlorn look at his
> faithful speeder as he rounds a corner.

Some of Luke and Ben's dialogue made it into the film, but not the used <s>car</s> speeder dealership, which was deleted, presumably because it adds little to the plot.

[image]
<sub><sup>hat tip to [Megaptera novaeangliae](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/135443/megaptera-novaeangliae) for the reminder.</sup></sub>

---

We learn in the [junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization)) that he sold his speeder for 2000 Imperial credits (described in the [original novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) as "*a number of small metal shapes*").

> Facing the speeder dealer, Luke said, “All right, give it to me, I’ll
> take it.” The speeder dealer, an insectoid alien, had finally agreed
> to buy Luke’s cherished landspeeder for two thousand credits.

---

The scene made it into the Marvel comic adaptation, [issue #2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_2:_Six_Against_the_Galaxy)

[image]

### Legends

We have some additional info about the creature that purchased the speeder, a vuvrian called [Wioslea](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wioslea/Legends). The company that she worked for was called [Spaceport Speeders](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Spaceport_Speeders).

The negotiations were captured in the [Star Wars Radio Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio_series)#Star_Wars).

> **Luke Skywalker:** *I want to sell this speeder.*
> **Obi-Wan Kenobi:** *If we can get a fair price.*
> **Luke Skywalker:** *Yeah. I paid twenty-four hundred for it, and I put a lot of work into it. I think it's worth a lot more.*
> **Wioslea:** *Fifteen hundred is all I can offer you, human.*
> **Luke Skywalker:** *Fifteen hundred? Look, this landspeeder's in great shape, even if it's not very pretty.*
> **Obi-Wan Kenobi:** *We can accept no less than two thousand.*
> **Wioslea:** *Your grip on reality is fragile, humans. It's the newer models that are in demand now, not these old ones. I shall probably have to sell it at a loss.*
> **Obi-Wan Kenobi:** *But it's still not a fair price.*
> **Wioslea:** *You touch a responsive chord in my… charitable nature, humans. Sixteen hundred.*

And it was confirmed in the EU novel [*Star Wars Journal: The Fight for Justice*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Journal:_The_Fight_for_Justice) that Obi-Wan used a Jedi mind-trick to convince Wioslea to pay precisely what the Jedi needed to pay for passage off the planet.

> We left Solo and Chewie at the cantina and headed over to a used
> speeder lot with Artoo and Threepio. As usual, the dealer tried to cut
> us down in price, and Ben's use of the Force saved us again. We needed
> two thousand for Captain Solo, and that's what Ben got us. I'm sure
> the dealer's going to wonder why he was so generous when he recovers,
> but he can still sell the landspeeder at a profit, so we didn't feel
> too badly.

The speeder ended up being purchased from the used speeder lot and used by a racer called Wade Vox in the game [Star Wars: Demolition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Demolition).

[image]

We have confirmation from [Star Wars Insider #50](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_50) that this was indeed Luke's speeder.

At the end of the game Wade is killed and the fate of the speeder is unknown, but presumably it ends up in the possession of Jabba the Hutt.

Comment: I saw *Star Wars -- A New Hope* when it first came out (back when it was simply called *Star Wars*) and this dialog **was** in the film. I remember when Luke left his landspeeder the last thing he did before walking away was grab his cloak and sling it over his shoulder. Then came the dialog. But I don't remember seeing him turn around and take a last look. And if you've never seen that you must be a youngling!

Comment: Why does the Marvel comic have random **words** in boldface? These are not the words you would **emphasize**.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - I don't **know**, but it's the same throughout the **entire series**, without any **obvious** pattern; https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us14A.jpg

Comment: @Valorum The practice seems to **foreshadow** the random links apparently **automatically** inserted into Wikipedia **articles**. But **worse**, the Death Star [**greebles**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeble) in that page don't look **canonical** at all.  (Also, how **sleazy** can a used-speeder lot **become**? Does the dealer run a sand-meth house in the **backyard**?)

Comment: They wasted brain cells *naming* the used speeder dealer that they should have invested into Episodes 1-3...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I *liked* the prequel trilogy.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - I think I can imagine reading the text while emphasizing the bold words. It kinda works... Although it does quickly get difficult to focus on them and keep recreating the emphasis.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer They are not the words people would emphasize as they spoke, but words the authors want to make extra sure the readers pick up. At least that's how I see it. The linked image by Valorum corroborrates that, in my opinion.

Comment: @Jennifer - Isn't that dialogue in every version of *Star Wars*?? Even the ones Lucas mucked about with?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not familiar with "every version" of Star Wars; I just know the OP implied that the landspeeder sale was *not* in the version they were referring to.  And I do know that film editors have a (despicable) habit of cutting out footage to make a movie fit.

Comment: @Jennifer - Heh, quite. :-)

Answer (score 28):

It's shown that he sold it to pay for their passage on the Falcon.

> LUKE: Look at this. Ever since the XP-38 came out, they just aren't in
> demand.
>
> BEN: It'll be enough.

Comment: Huh, maybe I missed that bit of dialogue in the film. Is that after they’ve walked in to the cantina?

Comment: After they've talked to Han and he's made arrangements to meet them in docking bay 94 (and after the scene with Greedo, and the droids hiding from the stormtroopers).

Comment: Ahhh ok. Since this is just me missing dialogue from the film I’ll probably just delete this question then.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - I'm just putting together a slightly more detailed answer.

Comment: Ok. Do you guys think it’s worth keeping this open since it was a mistake on my part?

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - "he sold it" is only a small part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I just saw your answer. I didn’t know that was a missing scene!

Comment: @MissouriSpartan this is a great QA, do not delete it !

Comment: @Fattie nah it’ll stay

Comment: This bit of dialogue is one example of Lucas being a car buff going back to his teen years. I can picture a character in American Graffiti saying almost the same thing about a '54 Chevy or similar.

Answer (score 2):

*[Tatooine Manhunt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tatooine_Manhunt)*, a WEG D6 Adventure, has the option of buying Luke's landspeeder from the Speeder Salesman, selling it along with others to the PCs.

> Spaceport Speeders is a repulsor vehicle shop that rents, sells, and
> buys land- and airspeeders. In fact, Luke Skywalker’s landspeeder is
> on sale — for 4,000 credits! Other than that, there are only two
> landspeeders available — an old Mobquet A-l and a rebuilt Ubrikkian.
> The heavy influx of bounty hunters has cleaned the shop out. Three
> bumbling, rather inept-looking bounty hunters haggle with the shop
> owner about the price of Luke's old vehicle, and Zardra (see the
> pullout) eyes the Ubrikkian when the PCs reach this encounter. She
> greets them with a chilling smile, and finishes her purchase

Pretty fun thing they added.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it adds extra information from a different source. I assume this is Legends? Also do you have an image, video or something else from the game you could [edit] in to back this up?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - All of these RPGs are Legends.